# How can I connect a value of an range input with an output tag?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to connect my input range value change with an output. I mean when I move the range input the current value should be shown in the site. I tried it via using `form` with `"oninput"` and `<output>`. It works but I would like to know how to use it with JS. When I use `forEach`, the one input value which I change applies on other inputs. How to change only the corresponding output?

Below the image

[image])

**My code:**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const filters = document.querySelectorAll(".filters input"),
    output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

  function handleUpdate() {
    const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || "";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      `--${this.name}`,
      this.value + suffix
    );
    output.forEach((out) => {
      out.value = this.value;
    });
  }

  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("change", handleUpdate));
  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("mousemove", handleUpdate));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <label>
    Blur:
    <input
      name="blur"
      data-sizing="px"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      value="0"
      id="blur"
    />
    <output name="result" for="blur">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Invert:
    <input
      name="invert"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="invert"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Sepia:
    <input
      name="sepia"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="sepia"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Saturate:
    <input
      name="saturate"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="200"
      value="100"
      id="saturate"
    />
    <output name="result">100</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Hue rotate:
    <input
      name="hue"
      data-sizing="deg"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="360"
      value="0"
      id="hue"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please share ALL the necessary code needed to reproduce your problem,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You are looping with every call of `handleUpdate` through all `output` with `output.forEach(...`. Why? You should just update the value of the corresponding output. If you post your HTML we can tell you how to select that output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping with every call of `handleUpdate()` through all `output` elements with `output.forEach(...`. To select only the corresponding `output` element you could use `nextElementSibling` (if the next sibling is the `output`):

```js
this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value;
```

**Working example:**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const filters = document.querySelectorAll(".filters input"),
    output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

  function handleUpdate() {
    const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || "";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      `--${this.name}`,
      this.value + suffix
    );
    this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value;
  }

  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("change", handleUpdate));
  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("mousemove", handleUpdate));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <label>
    Blur:
    <input
      name="blur"
      data-sizing="px"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      value="0"
      id="blur"
    />
    <output name="result" for="blur">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Invert:
    <input
      name="invert"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="invert"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Sepia:
    <input
      name="sepia"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="sepia"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Saturate:
    <input
      name="saturate"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="200"
      value="100"
      id="saturate"
    />
    <output name="result">100</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Hue rotate:
    <input
      name="hue"
      data-sizing="deg"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="360"
      value="0"
      id="hue"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively you could select the parent with `parentElement`and then the `output`, for example if the `output` isn't a direct sibling of the input:

```js
this.parentElement.querySelector('output').value = this.value;
```

**Working example:**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const filters = document.querySelectorAll(".filters input"),
    output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

  function handleUpdate() {
    const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || "";
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      `--${this.name}`,
      this.value + suffix
    );
    this.parentElement.querySelector('output').value = this.value;
  }

  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("change", handleUpdate));
  filters.forEach((input) => input.addEventListener("mousemove", handleUpdate));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <label>
    Blur:
    <input
      name="blur"
      data-sizing="px"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="10"
      value="0"
      id="blur"
    />
    <output name="result" for="blur">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Invert:
    <input
      name="invert"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="invert"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Sepia:
    <input
      name="sepia"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="100"
      value="0"
      id="sepia"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Saturate:
    <input
      name="saturate"
      data-sizing="%"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="200"
      value="100"
      id="saturate"
    />
    <output name="result">100</output>
  </label>

  <label>
    Hue rotate:
    <input
      name="hue"
      data-sizing="deg"
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="360"
      value="0"
      id="hue"
    />
    <output name="result">0</output>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made for me a quick example to understand what you want to achieve.
Just add a listener for each range input and put in the output input value of range input after change is made.

HTML

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="3" id="range">
<input type="text" disabled id="output">
```

JS

```js
document.querySelector("#range").addEventListener("change", ({target}) => {
   document.querySelector("#output").value = target.value
})
```

---

If you have many inputs and you want to add this to corresponding ones... you can rearrange the HTML and use `querySelectorAll` and loop through this NodeList and you have this solution

HTML

```html
<label><input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input"><input type="text" disabled class="output-input"></label>
<label><input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input"><input type="text" disabled class="output-input"></label>
<label><input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input"><input type="text" disabled class="output-input"></label>
```

JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll("label").forEach(label => {
   label.querySelector(".range-input").addEventListener("change", ({target}) => {
      label.querySelector(".output-input").value = target.value
   })
})
```

**Working example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("label").forEach(label => {
  label.querySelector(".range-input").addEventListener("change", ({target}) => {
    label.querySelector(".output-input").value = target.value
  })
})
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input">
  <input type="text" disabled class="output-input">
</label>

<label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input">
  <input type="text" disabled class="output-input">
</label>

<label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="3" class="range-input">
  <input type="text" disabled class="output-input">
</label>
```

Comment: true :) totally forgot I just copy and paste it... I'll edit it :) Good catch